# Disabling asp button in ascx layout template with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to use javascript/jquery to disable a button on the click of a checkbox but am having a hard time.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvApplicationForms" OnItemCommand="lvAttachedDocuments_OnItemCommand"
            DataKeyNames="FormID" OnPreRender="lvApplicationForms_PreRender" OnItemDataBound="lvApplicationForms_ItemDataBound">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table class="formData_tb" style="margin-top: 0px" cellspacing="0px" width="590px">

                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemplaceholder" runat="server" />
                    <tr style="background-color: #dedede">
                        <td class="fieldData_td"></td>
                        <td class="fieldName_td" colspan="2">All Documents
                        </td>
                        <td class="fieldData_td" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSignAll" runat="server" Text="" onclick="javascript:return CheckedChange(this)" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="fieldData_td" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbExposeAll" runat="server" Text="" onclick="javascript:return CheckedChange(this)" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="fieldData_td" colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" Text="Save" Style="width: 80px;" CssClass="formButton"
                                OnClick="btnSaveChanges_Click" OnClientClick="EnableUploadValidators(false)" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
```

For testing purposes I have a javascript function that fires off when either checkbox (ID's: cbSignAll, cbExposeAll) is checked. The javascript needs to disable the save button (ID: btnSaveChanges).

I'm able to get the javascript function to fire, but I can't seem to grab the button's properties to disable it.

Javascript:

```
function CheckedChange(objCheckBox) {
    $('.btnSaveChanges').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a class selector, not an ID selector.  Try $("#btnSaveChanges").attr(...)

Also, this looks like Webforms, so watch out for the engine's auto-formatted ids.  Right-click on the submit button and inspect it to make sure the element's ID is actually "btnSaveChanges".   Sometimes it will get renamed to something like ctl100_btnSaveChanges, depending on the rendering mode you're using in ASP.NET webforms.

Comment: Have you verified that the button's id is actually btnSaveChanges in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP modifies ID of elements and prepends form and other data at beginning of ID, and in this case it also adds index of element at the end. (check with dev tools)

You can use wildcard selector to get the needed element:

```
$("[id*=btnSaveChanges]").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.9 you should use prop() when editing the disabled property.

```
function CheckedChange(objCheckBox) {
    $('#btnSaveChanges').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

As also stated in other answers asp child controls can have their id's amended, unless you state ClientIDMode="Static" for the page, so you need to ensure that the id is correct or alter the selector to a like selector shown in @Tomislav Muic's answer.